# CorePlot - dynamic x-axis data using two arrays

Tags: dynamic, plot, nsmutablearray, core-plot, axis-labels

This is more of an open discussion topic than anything else.  Currently I'm storing 50 `Float32` values in my `NSMutableArray *voltageArray` before I refresh my `CPTPlot *plot`.  Every time I obtain 50 values, I remove the previous 50 from the `voltageArray` and repeat the process....always displaying the 50 values in "real time" on my plot.

However, the data I'm receiving (which is voltage coming from a Cypress BLE module equipped with a pressure transducer) is so quick that any variation (0.4 V to 4.0 V; no pressure to lots of pressure) cannot be seen on my graph.  It just shows up as a straight line, varying up and down without showing increased or decreased slopes.

To show overall change, I wanted to take those 50 values, store them in the first index of another `NSMutableArray *stampArray` and use the index of `stampArray` to display information.  Meanwhile, the `numberOfRecordsForPlot:` method would look like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plotnumberOfRecords {
    return (DATA_PER_STAMP * _stampCount);
}
```

This would initially be 50, then after 50 pieces of data are captured from the BLE module, `_stampCount` would increase by one, and the number of records for plot would increase by 50 (till about 2500-10000 range, then I'd refresh the whole the thing and restart the process.)

Is this the right approach?  How would I be able to make the first 50 points stay on the graph, while building the next 50, etc.?  Imagine an `y = x^2` graph, and what the graph looks like when applying integration (the whole breaking the area under the curve into rectangles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the "Real Time Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app included with Core Plot. It starts off with an empty plot, adding a new point each cycle until reaching the maximum number of points. After that, one old point is removed for each new one added so the total number stays constant. The demo uses a timer to pass random data to the plot, but your app can of course collect data from anywhere. Be sure to always interact with the graph from the main thread.

I doubt you'll be able to display 10,000 data points on one plot (does your display have enough pixels to resolve that many points?). If not, you'll get much better drawing performance if you filter and/or smooth the data to remove some of the points before sending them to the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and that's pretty much what I'm after.  2500-10000 was an uneducated estimate; if anything > 1000 makes the performance suffer than going the "< 1000" route will work.  Regarding Plot Gallery, what specific classes/methods should I look at to see the add and removal of points?  I'm new to this so I'm still trying to get my head around it all.

Comment: Look at `-newData:` in `RealTimePlot.m`.

Comment: Awesome, looks pretty straightforward.  Grazie

Comment: Also, as a follow-up question: when exactly does `numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` get called by the data source?  When is an actual change to the plot is recognized?  I noticed that whenever I sent the message `[self.graph reloadData]` (after I captured 50 data points), the delegate method would get called.   In terms of the 'newData:` method, when would the `numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` get called?  I would assume after since `newData:` sets the `self.currentIndex` and `self.plot` properties.  Or does it not get called at all?

Comment: The `-reloadData` method sets a flag that tells the plot that new data is available. The next time the Core Animation system decides to redraw the layers, the plot loads the new data before drawing. `-reloadData` causes the plot to reload all of its data while the `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` only loads the new points while leaving the existing data alone.